# Can i run more then one main select statments on the 2 with tables?

Tags: sql

Hay All,

is it possible to run more than 1 select statement after using with?
first select statement works fine, as soon as i add another select statement i got a error.

```
with 
a as (select a,b,c from Table1 with(readuncommitted)),
b as (select d,e,f from Table2 with(readuncommitted))

select * from a
select * from b
```

expected output:
Table 1
a
Table 2
b

Answer (score 0):

Well the way CTEs will behave is that they will only be in scope for the first query, but not the second.  You *could* perhaps do a union query here:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, 'Table1' AS src FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT d, e, f, 'Table2' FROM b;
```

Or, you could move the `b` CTE to before the second query:

```sql
WITH a AS ( 
    SELECT a, b, c
    FROM Table1
    WITH(readuncommitted)
)

SELECT * FROM a;

WITH b AS ( 
    SELECT d, e, f
    FROM Table2
    WITH(readuncommitted)
)

SELECT * FROM b;
```

Answer (score 0):

hay DasD,
You can not use multiple select for cte, but you can use more than one CTE like this.

```
with 
a as (select a,b,c from Table1 with(readuncommitted)),
b as (select d,e,f from Table2 with(readuncommitted))

select * from a,b
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explain to the database, what you wantfrom bith tables.

as both have the same structure you can use `UNION` to join them vertically

```
with 
a as (select a,b,c from Table1 with(readuncommitted)),
b as (select d,e,f from Table2 with(readuncommitted))

select * from a
UNION
select * from b
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
"A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns."

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)